# Seeing random java.net.SocketException: Cannot allocate memory on MacOS

Tags: java, udp, netty, nio

I'm using Netty for multicast group subscription and I'm running into a pretty big snag on MacOS 10.8.x. When attempting to join a group I'm randomly seeing this exception:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Cannot allocate memory
at sun.nio.ch.Net.joinOrDrop4(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.join4(Net.java:421)
at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.innerJoin(DatagramChannelImpl.java:848)
at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.join(DatagramChannelImpl.java:866)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannel.joinGroup(NioDatagramChannel.java:158)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannel.joinGroup(NioDatagramChannel.java:135)
at com.soterawireless.h1s.groups.NioGroupSubscriber.joinGroup(NioGroupSubscriber.java:203)
... 5 more
```

Has anyone seen this exception before? I'm not having any problems running the same app on either Windows or Linux. This is only happening on the Mac. Any insight into the differences on MacOS that might be causing this would be greatly appreciated.

-Brian

Comment: Uh, I have already seen that... As far as I recall, this is a problem with the *BSD kernel Mac OS X is using... Have you googled yet?

Comment: I've googled the heck out of it but haven't found any resolution. Any hints on what the kernel problem might be? Perhaps I'm not googling from the right angle.

Comment: Have you stumbled upon [this URL](http://appletoolbox.com/2010/05/java-for-mac-os-x-10-6-update-2-memory-leaks-other-problems-how-to-fix/)?

Comment: I have indeed. Unfortunately we can't revert to jdk6 as we're relying on the NIO multicast features released with jdk7. I'm wondering if there's a problem with the NIO multicast implementation on MacOS? There's been a number of issues that have cropped up since Apple ditched Java-Mac development and passed the baton to Oracle.

Comment: Uh sorry, I really cannot recall anything more useful :/ At this point I believe your best bet is to bang on your favourite search engine(s) with related keywords and refine...